# Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php

I have this very simple program in PHP that does not want to work. It returns the same error as topic for unknown reasons to me.

```
$file = 'counter.txt';
$counter = file_get_contents($file);
if(flock($file, LOCK_EX)){
    $counter += 1;
    echo $counter;
    $write = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Unable');
    fwrite($write, $counter);
    flock($file,LOCK_UN);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things out of order,

```
$file = 'counter.txt';
$counter = file_get_contents($file);
$write = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Unable'); //move this line

if(flock($write, LOCK_EX)){  //-- change this
   $counter += 1;
    echo $counter;
    fwrite($write, $counter);
    flock($write,LOCK_UN); //-- change this
}
```

The main problem is `flock` takes a (stream)resource as it's input, and the filename is just a string.  So instead of `$file` you just need to use `$write` which is your file handle (resource), and then move `fopen` before the `flock` call.

If you are writing a single line do this instead

```
$file = 'counter.txt';
$counter += 1;
if(!file_put_contents($file, $counter, LOCK_EX)) or die('Unable');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

It's pretty much equivalent to what you have there.  Well except it's way shorter `3 vs 9 lines`, easier, and Kooler.

I could even reduce this further down to 1 line:

```
  if(!file_put_contents('counter.txt', ++$counter, LOCK_EX)) or die('Unable');
```

The `LOCK_EX` flag is Lock exclusive, basically the same thing as `flock`, just in this case PHP handles all the file stream stuff for you.

The real difference is if you do this in a loop, it's expensive getting file handles so to loop output into `file_put_content` is way less efficient then to open the file (outside the loop) and write to the same handle during inside a loop.

Hesse the reason I said this above.

> If you are writing a single line do this instead

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, I'll mark it as solved as soon as it lets me. Why does it matter if fopen is within or outside the if-statement?

Comment: It doesn't so much about `if` in general, `flock` takes a file stream resource, not a file name. in this case its `$write` or in other words the thing you get back from `fopen`. Hence the error `Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given`  Therefore there is no way to put it in the if.

Comment: Ok, I figured the error was something like that but it's my first time writing PHP so knowledge is very limited.

Comment: As I said in the aswer, `file_put_content` may be a better choice if you are writing  a single line.  But it's good to learn too.  Just remember that fopen returns a file resource, and then this error would make more sense to you.  You can even do `echo gettype($write)` and it will say `resource`.  Good luck and Happy PHP coding!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/flock-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)
Solution was to give Apache group (www-data) read and write permissions to /storage/framework/cache applying recursively.